# jQuery: Creating a New DOM element and showing it

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, dom, element

So as the title suggests I wish to create a new dom element (the HTML is generated and retrieved via AJAX). I kind of got it working but it appears hidden, and when I try to Fade In it breaks!

```
   function AddContent(Content) {
        div = document.createElement(Content)
        div.appendTo($("#contentAreas"));
        //    $(div).fadeIn("slow");
        }
```

It basically inserts the item into the correct position but doesn't show it. When I attempt to fade it in, it's fails to do so. No errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be more descriptive?  *How* does it break?  What does "Content" look like?  What does "#contentAreas" look like?

Comment: Also, what happens if you do:
    $("#contentAreas").append(div);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div needs to be jQuery for appendTo to work.  Try this:

```
 function AddContent( content ) {
     $(content).appendTo("#contentAreas").fadeIn("slow");
 }
```

Comment: Damien, note that appendTo takes a selector so you can just do .appendTo("#contentAreas"). Saves creating another jquery object for no reason

Comment: @redsquare -- thanks for pointing that out. I've updated as it makes the code cleaner. Internally, though, I think the first thing appendTo does is jQuery(selector).

Comment: @tvanfosson -- indeed, helps save a few keystrokes however!!

Answer (score 5):

Should be `$(div).appendTo(...)`. Or you could change how `div` is created to `div = $(Content)`, perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need createElement, the jQuery constructor can take html as a parameter (assuming that content is an html string):

```
function AddContent(content) {
   var div = $(content);
   div.appendTo($("#contentAreas"));
   $(div).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
   function AddContent(Content) {
        div = $('<div>' + Content + '</div>');           
        div.appendTo($("#contentAreas")).fadeIn("slow");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The appendTo takes a selector so it does not need to be a jquery object as all the other examples above have it.

```
function AddContent( content ) {
     $(content).appendTo("#contentAreas").fadeIn("slow");
 }
```